# HttpURLConnection update from Http Client

Tags: java, php, android, httpurlconnection

Hello I was wondering if somebody could help me with the following, I have a database that is currently populated. I used to call it using the http client and it worked fine but now I'm trying to update the code since its been deprecated to use the httpurlconnection but i have no success. I ve looked up some tutorials and tried a few thing but it doesn't seem to be working. the database is called through a php file and returns it in a json format.If i were to call the php file from my browser the response is the following: [{"id":"15","logo":"logo url","title":"title"}]

The error that I get on the console is the following:java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.InputStream.close()' on a null object reference

Which its not making much sense to me since the script pulls information

I have the following code, i left the commented section just in case i need any of it, It also includes the old way i used to call the DB Thank you!:

public void loadNews(){
        InputStream is = null;

```
    String result = "";
 ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://databasecall.php");
        //HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        //urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        //urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
        //urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        //urlConnection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        //urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        //urlConnection.setReadTimeout(15000);
        //urlConnection.connect();
        int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        Log.i("Tag:", Integer.toString(responseCode)); //tag 200
        //HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://databasecall.php");
        //httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        //HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        //HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        //is = entity.getContent();

    /*}catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }*/

        //convert response to string
        //try{
        //BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            //BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
            Log.i("Tag:", result);
        }
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
```

Comment: You're opening `InputStream in` .. but you're closing `is.close();`.  Whoops :)

Comment: that did it! haha pops is right its always those little things where should i put the close tho?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated API

```
try {
        String urlParameters =  "name=toni&class=one&param3=ok"; 
        byte[] postData = urlParameters.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        int postDataLength = postData.length;
        String request = "http://rocks.php";
        URL url = new URL(request);
        HttpURLConnection cox = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        cox.setDoOutput(true);
        cox.setDoInput(true);
        cox.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        cox.setRequestMethod("POST");
        cox.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        cox.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
        cox.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
                Integer.toString(postDataLength));
        cox.setUseCaches(false);
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
                cox.getOutputStream());

        writer.write(urlParameters);
        writer.flush();
        String line;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                cox.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        writer.close();
        reader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        result = e.toString();
        Sucess = false;
        e.printStackTrace();
 }
```